# Custom properties on attachments are not preserved when encrypting/signing emails

Tags: c++, outlook, outlook-addin, smime

I have an C++ Outlook addin. when a message with an attachment is sent, I set a custom property on the attachment, and I can read it at the receiver's side.

However, when the sender encrypts/signs the message, my property disappears and I cannot read it in the receiver's side. I also checked in OutlookSpy and I cannot see my property on the attachment or on the underlying p7m attachment.

Does outlook delete custom properties upon encryption/signing or hides them somewhere? is there a way to preserve the property?

Answer (score 0):

Outlook loses custom properties (MailItem.UserPorperties) even for the regular unencrypted messages unless you send in the RTF format (TNEF - the infamous winmail.dat attachment) or between two Exchange mailboxes.

This is to be expected.

Comment: I'm indeed referring to emails sent between two Exchange mailboxes, where properties on attachments are preserved for plain emails, but not when the email is encrypted/signed.

Comment: This is to be expected - p7m attachment contains the data converted to MIME, all MAPI specific properties are lost.